display values in dbforge studio for mysql instead of checkboxes
The output grid in dbForge Studio for mySql is very nice except for the checkbox display it uses for unsigned bit columns. Can it be set to display the actual bit column values e.g. 1 or 0 instead of a checkbox?
Microsoft's SQL Management Studio has the option to display query output in text or grid format? I do not see a similar option for dbForge Studio for mySQL. Does it exist?
I checked the options under settings in the app as anyone would do. Perhaps I missed it?

I don't think there is a built-in option to display bit values (1 or 0) in the result grid instead of checkboxes. Maybe you can contact DEVART requesting this feature.

To display the actual bit values (1 or 0) instead of a checkbox in the output grid of dbForge Studio for MySQL, you can use a workaround by modifying your query. Here’s an approach you can take for BIT and BOOLEAN data types to get more control over the display format.
For a BIT column:
CREATE TABLE your_table ( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    is_active bit(1)); 
  
  
INSERT INTO your_table (id, is_active) VALUES (1, TRUE);  -- Inserts TRUE (1) 
INSERT INTO your_table (id, is_active) VALUES (2, FALSE); -- Inserts FALSE (0) 
 
 
SELECT  
    id, 
    CASE WHEN is_active = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_active_binary 
FROM  
    your_table; 


For a BOOLEAN column:
CREATE TABLE your_table ( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    is_active BOOLEAN 
); 
  
INSERT INTO your_table (id, is_active) VALUES (1, TRUE);  -- Inserts TRUE (1) 
INSERT INTO your_table (id, is_active) VALUES (2, FALSE); -- Inserts FALSE (0) 
  
  SELECT  
    id, 
    CASE WHEN is_active = 1 THEN '✔' ELSE ' ' END AS is_active_checkbox 
FROM  
    your_table;  


In this setup, is_active_binary will return either 1 or 0. If you prefer a visual representation using a checkbox-like display, is_active_checkbox will display a checkmark (✔) for TRUE and a blank for FALSE.
If you encounter any issues, feel free to reach out at support@devart.com.

This is not the answer which is about the dbForge IDE. Instead you are showing how to write SQL logic to display derived values based on logic. Its neat but defeats the object of using an IDE to look at the actual data. I guess the real asnwer is that, no, dbForge Studio for mySql can not display raw values of BIT (or BOOLEAN) columns.
